# How do I use an indexed PNG image as a texture for SDL2/OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2, libpng

My code for loading images seems to work for 24 and 32bit images. I load an image in using SDL2_image:

```
// Snip cruft above
if((surface = IMG_Load(filename.c_str())) == NULL) {
    error = "Unable to load file: " + filename;
    throw error.c_str();
}


// get the number of channels in the SDL surface
nOfColors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;

if (nOfColors == 4) {    // contains an alpha channel
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGBA;
    else
        texture_format = GL_BGRA;
} else if (nOfColors == 3) {    // no alpha channel
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGB;
    else
        texture_format = GL_BGR;
} else {
    error = "error: the image is not truecolor..  this will probably break (" + filename + " contains " + std::to_string(nOfColors) + " bytes per pixel)";
    throw error.c_str();
}
// snip OpenGL stuff below
```

nOfColors only contains the value 1 because the PNG is saved as an indexed color space. GIMP opens the file fine, including an alpha channel.

How can I convert the surface to a truecolor texture so I can use it for rendering on an OpenGL quad?

If this is not possible (or impractical) how do I save the PNG as a truecolor image with an alpha channel. I've tried ImageMagick:

```
convert image.png -depth 32 image.png
```

But the image still seems to save as an indexed color image

As some extra background info - the program was working with SDL1.2, but stopped working after porting to SDL2. I've updated everything else to SDL2, but there may have been changes in the way SDL2_image works that I'm not aware of.

Comment: If conversion is an option, use it. If not, you can always fall back to using `new_surface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(surface, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA888, 0)`. Don't forget to to free old surf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert it to the right format using `SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat()`...

```
SDL_Surface *image = ...;
SDL_Surface *converted = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(
    image, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force `ImageMagick` to create a 32-bit image (i.e. 8-bits per channel plus alpha) like this:

```
convert image.png PNG32:image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Under ImageMagick bizarre language, indexed image is just one with the "color type" number 3 (Palette).

So, to generate a png without a palette with the convert command, you must:

```
convert -type TrueColorAlpha image_in.png image_out.png
```